# jgrapht SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph normalizing weights

Tags: java, jgrapht

I am using SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph in an application. 
I would like to have the edge weights normalized.

Does anyone know of any faster method to do this, or should I just go through all the weights, find min and max, and then go through the weights again, in order to replace them with the normalized value?

Thanks in advance.